# Generalised Symmetric group and Semidirect Product

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups, semidirect-product, wreath-product

$G= \mathbb{Z}_r \wr \mathfrak{S}_n:=(\mathbb{Z}_r)^n\rtimes\mathfrak{S}_n$ is the generalised symmetric group where the element $G$ is denoted by $(f,\pi)$ where $f:\{1,2,\dots n\}\to \mathbb{Z}_r$ (ie., an element of $(\mathbb{Z}_r)^n)$ and $\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n$. The group operation  $$(g,\sigma)\cdot(f,\pi)=(g\cdot (f\circ\sigma^{-1}), \sigma\pi).$$ I understand that this is the usual semidirect product operation.

We can think symmetric group as two ways in which it permutes $n$ boxes (corresponds to natural left-right actions of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ ). Let us say $n=4$ and we have boxes numbers(value) 1,2,3,4 placed in for corner vertices of square named (position) I,II,III,IV. Then $\mathfrak{S}_4$ acts either by

1. by permuting positions I,II,III,IV (this corresponds to natural left action of $\mathfrak{S}_4$)
2. or by permuting values or box numbers 1,2,3,4. (this corresponds to natural right action of $\mathfrak{S}_4$)

I belive just like we think symmetric group by its action of permuting $n$ boxes. The generalised symmetric group can also be thought as "sort of permuting n-groups" instead of boxes.

Lets us say $r=3$ now one may think we have stuck equilateral triangle in the corner vertices of square. See the attached figure. [image] Now we can rotate any of these triangle and also permute these triangles. A symmetry of this object is pair of operation

1. Rotating each triangles
2. and permuting triangles.

This is exactly encoded in the data $(f,\pi)\in G$. But my worry is how did we encoded this data?

- Qn 01: what do we mean by $f(i)$? is $f(i)$ an operation to performed on triangle in the $I^{th}$ position or the operation to be performed to $ i^{th} $ triangle?
- Qn 02: How does $\mathfrak{S}_4$ acts? whether by permuting positions or the value/numbers.
- Qn 03: How do we see that operation in the semi direct product is natural in this context? that is by First rotate triangles by $f(i)$ then permute by $\pi$  and then again rotate by $g(j)$ and finally permute $\sigma$ by is the same as the product given in semidirect product.

---

PS: These are so confusing and had spent a lot of time to fix this before bringing this here. Kindly help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Other than that, I think this is a good set of questions (+1).

Comment: I don't know the efficient way to breaking this question, that's why I am forced to make this.

Comment: The answer to both of the first two questions is "it depends".  You could define this action as either a right action or a left action, and it will reverse the answer.  (The same is already true just in the symmetric group, where it is a source of widespread and unavoidable confusion and misunderstanding.)

Comment: As for question 3, you will not be puzzled about it once you have established a set of conventions that resolve questions 1 and 2, because you will be able to do concrete examples and see how it combines.